# Oracle Problems in obtaining data from the last list

Tags: php, oracle

I have a problem in finding latest data from the database.

When I `select no from book` is returned from 1,2,3.

But when I do this, supposedly think it should return the value 3 this returns me 2.

```
SELECT no FROM book WHERE rowid =( SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM book)
```

The strange this is that if you delete all data from the list, it starts me back the last line as well, until it has more than 2 data. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try over this

```
select no from book where rowid = (select max(no) from book)
```

Comment: The `rowid` isn't going to be equal to `no` for any row.

Comment: SELECT no FROM book WHERE no =( SELECT MAX(no) FROM book) Thz my fault :X

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your query is looking for the max of rowid, and not no.

Therefore, try this:

```
SELECT MAX(no) FROM book;
```

Comment: The `rowid` isn't going to be equal to `no` for any row.

Comment: Was going off of the asker's query. Fixed to simplify it even more ;)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be using `max(no)` in your subquery?

```
SELECT no FROM book WHERE rowid =( SELECT MAX(no) FROM book)
```

RowID is a psuedocolumn and starts at 0 - [see here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm).

Comment: SELECT no FROM book WHERE no =( SELECT MAX(no) FROM book) Thz my fault :X

Comment: `rowid` doesn't start at 0.  One component of it does -- the row number within the block -- but it includes other information.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `SELECT MAX(no) FROM book`?